# How can I get the string from my HTML form onto the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, boolean

I'm trying to compare a selected response from a form to the correct answer, so that I can show a "Correct!" or "Incorrect!" page next. I'm using jQuery to establish what the selected answer was for any given question, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to target the actual content of the response option instead of just it's value or some other component from the HTML, because these will be different for every question set.

Here is the html template for the questions and responses from script store.js

```
function renderQuestion() {
    console.log("hello");
    let questions = STORE.questions[questionNumber];
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container" align="center">
        ${questions.image}
          <p>${questions.questionText}<br></p>
          <form method="post" onsubmit="return nextQuestion()">
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[0]}<br>
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[1]}<br>
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[2]}<br>
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[3]}<br>
              <button type="submit" id="choose" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
      </div>`);
      $("main").html(questionTemplate);
}
```

here is the function I'm working on- the console should be logging the text of the response option but it's showing "on" when I use .val(), or undefined or some other randomness depending on what method I try:

```
function checkAnswer() {
$("main").on("click","#choose",function(event){
    let questions = STORE.questions[questionNumber];
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    let chosenAnswer=$("input[name=choice]:checked").val();
    console.log(chosenAnswer);
```

here is the rest of that function, displaying the correct! or incorrect! screens. It's always showing the incorrect screen right now, because I can't get the chosenAnswer variable setup correctly.

```
    if (!chosenAnswer) {
        alert ("Select One");
        return;
    }
    if(chosenAnswer===questions.answer) {
    const correctResponse = $(`
    <div class="container" align="center">
    ${questions.image}
    <h4>${questions.answer}</h4>
    <p>Correct!<p>
    <button type="submit" id="next" value="submit">Next</button>
    </div>`);
    $("main").html(correctResponse);}
    else{
    const inCorrectResponse = $(`
    <div class="container" align="center">
    ${questions.image}
    <p> Incorrect. <br> The correct answer is:</p>
    <h4>${questions.answer}</h4>
    <button type="submit" id="next" value="submit">Next</button>
    </div>`);
    $("main").html(inCorrectResponse);
    nextQuestion();}
})
}
```

These are some example questions from store.js. I'm using "answer" to be able to compare the selected response to the correct response.

```
const STORE = {
    questions: [ {
        image: `<div class="image"> <img src="nettles.svg", alt="mystery plant illustration"> </div>`,
            questionText: "Which plant provides the most minerals and nutrients.",
            responses: [
                "Licorice <i>Glycyrrhiza glabra</i>",
                "Jiagulon <i>Gynostemma pentaphyllum</i>",
                "Lemon Balm <i>Melissa Officianlis</i>",
                "Nettles <i>Urtica dioica</i>"
            ],
            answer: "Nettles <i>Urtica dioica</i>"
        },
        {
            questionText: "Which Plant is known for lowering  high cholesterol, high blood pressure, and improving heart function as well as improving memory, and preventing hair loss?",
            responses: [
                "Jiagulon <i>Gynostemma pentaphyllum</i>",
                "Licorice <i>Glycyrrhiza glabra</i>",
                "Nettles <i>Urtica dioica</i>",
                "Lemon Balm <i>Melissa Officianlis</i>"
            ],
            answer: "Jiagulon <i>Gynostemma pentaphyllum</i>"
        },
     ]
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different suggestions from what I've been able to research, but I think I'm just not familiar enough with form submissions and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[0]}
```

please take a look at your input element, it would return "on" since you did not assign a value for it.

it should be

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="${questions.responses[0]}">${questions.responses[0]}
```